# Apply a vtk filter on a specific variable

Tags: variables, filter, dataset, vtk

My dataset has more than one variable and I want to choose one of the variables to apply some filters to, how can I do that

The following code produces two variables temperature and pressure

```
vtkDataSetReader *reader = vtkDataSetReader::New();
reader->SetFileName("noise.vtk");
reader->Update();

 for(int i = 0; i < np; i++)
  cout<<" variable "<<reader->GetOutput()->GetPointData()>GetArrayName(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Vtk filters act on images, not on variables, although some filters like threshold can work based on the active array, but the way to do it can vary (check in the documentation of the filter you intend to use) :

- set explicitly the active scalars of the image before applying the filter (e.g http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/VectorFieldNonZeroExtraction )

  image->GetPointData()->SetActiveScalars("Magnitude");
- give the array to process to the relevant method of the filter (e.g  http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/ThresholdPoints )

  threshold->SetInputArrayToProcess(0, 0, 0, vtkDataObject::FIELD_ASSOCIATION_POINTS, "index");
- otherwise you can just ignore the array you are not interested in with vtkPassArray http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPassArrays.html#details

Comment: This answer should be accepted. `SetInputArrayToProcess` works perfectly!